# How to use combination of $and and $or in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new in Elasticsearch. I am trying to convert query below in MongoDB to elastic:

```
let TXs = await db.collection("transactions").find({
        $or: [
          {"sender.wallet.address": {$in: addresses}, currency: currency},
          {"receiver.wallet.address": {$in: addresses}, currency: currency}
        ]
      }).sort({unix: 1}).toArray().catch(console.error);
```

addresses is an array of strings. I used code block below, but I got error:

```
let TXs = await elasticClient.search({
      index: elasticIndex,
      "query": {
        "terms": {
          "should": [
            {"bool": {"must": [{"term": {"sender.wallet.address": addresses}}, {"term": {"currency": currency}}]}},
            {"bool": {"must": [{"term": {"receiver.wallet.address": addresses}}, {"term": {"currency": currency}}]}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }).catch(console.error);
```

Error:

> ResponseError: parsing_exception: [parsing_exception] Reason: Unknown
> key for a END_ARRAY in [query].

Could someone help how can I wrote it in Elastic?

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of your search query, you need to use the `should` clause, instead of the `terms` clause. Modify your query as

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "sender.wallet.address": "addresses"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "currency": currency
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "receiver.wallet.address": "addresses"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "currency": currency
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 1:**

Based on your MongoDB query,

```
{"sender.wallet.address": {$in: addresses}, currency: currency},
```

since you are using `$in`, you should replace the term query inside the bool must clause with the **terms** query, which will allow you to use arrays of strings, instead of a string.

Comment: thank you. Although I removed addresses double quotation because addresses is an array of strings. I don't get any error now. But the results are not same as mongoDB! Do you know why?

Comment: @weera please go through the updated part of the answer, and lmk if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: I answered the question. Please consider it.

Comment: @weera `filter` clause works like a AND logical operator and the `should` clause works like a logical OR operator. The only difference between the `must` and `filter` clauses is that in `filter` scoring is ignored whereas the `must` clause contributes to the score. **And you can use the combination of filter and should clause, in your query**

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code block to:

```
let TXs = await elasticClient.search({
      index: elasticIndex,
      query: {
        bool: {
          filter: {term: {currency: currency}},
          should: [
            {terms: {"sender.wallet.address": addresses}},
            {terms: {"receiver.wallet.address": addresses}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }).catch(console.error);
```

I don't get any errors now, but it seems "filter" and "should" cannot work in a harmony. If I remove the filter, I get some documents, but when I add the filter, I get nothing. I think I don't combine these two in a right way.